# Following in the footsteps of Jason Bourne

Tags: online-resources, international-travel, tips-and-tricks, pilgrimages

I'm not as traditional a pilgrim as many of Travel SE's distinguished members. I've visited a couple of film studios, however I thought it might be interesting to plan a trip following the shooting locations of some movie or other. Naturally, for travellers, something like [Raiders of the Lost Ark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raiders_of_the_Lost_Ark), or [Jurassic Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurassic_Park) would be memorable, but perhaps a little optimistic.

I am a bit partial to action movies, so following the Matt Damon sequence we have:

- [The Bourne Identity (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bourne_Identity_(2002_film))

> In addition to Paris, filming took place in Prague, Imperia, Rome,
>   Mykonos, and Zürich; several scenes set in Zürich were also filmed in
>   Prague.

- [The Bourne Supremacy (2004)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bourne_Supremacy_(film))

> The film was shot in reverse order of its settings: some portions of
>   the car chase and the film's ending were shot in Moscow, then most of
>   the rest of the film was shot in and around Berlin, and the opening
>   scenes in Goa were filmed last.

- [The Bourne Ultimatum (2007)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bourne_Ultimatum_(film))

> The Bourne Ultimatum was filmed at Pinewood Studios near London and in
>   multiple locations around the world, including Tangier, London, Paris,
>   Madrid (as itself and double for Turin), Berlin (as double for
>   Moscow), New York City including the Springs Mills Building (as the
>   deep cover CIA offices), and other locations in the U.S

- [The Bourne Legacy (2012)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bourne_Legacy_(film))

> Filming was primarily in New York City, with some scenes shot in the
>   Philippines, South Korea, Pakistan, and Canada

And this year's

- [Jason Bourne (2016)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Bourne_(film))

> In August 2015, producers met with Clark County, Nevada officials to
>   get approval to shoot on The Strip, requesting a shutdown of Las Vegas
>   Boulevard for several hours a day for seven to ten days. It was not
>   clear whether the producers obtained a license to do so. Damon told
>   Buzzfeed that the film would start production in September starting
>   from Greece (these scenes, set in Greece, were actually filmed in
>   Tenerife, Canary Islands) and Las Vegas, and would have Bourne in
>   "a post-Snowden world".
>
> Principal photography on the film commenced on September 8, 2015.
>   In early November, filming took place outside of Paddington Station in
>   London, England. In late-November 2015, filming took place in
>   Kreuzberg, Berlin. In early December 2015, filming started in
>   Washington, D.C., where the shooting took place at Constitution
>   Gardens. Filming in Las Vegas, Nevada was scheduled to begin on
>   January 14, 2016 until January 21. Production on the film
>   concluded on February 1, 2016. Filming also took place in March
>   2016 in Woolwich train station in Greenwich, London.

I could probably make my way to Paddington Station or the Las Vegas Strip, but some of the other films give locations that may be a bit hard to track down. The Bourne Identity sound like the most modest option for a European.

**Question**: How does one track down the locations, bridges, hotels, or other landmarks that would provide the essence of the "on location" parts of these movies in order to come up with a potential itinerary? Are there fan sites, or do the studios provide location details on request, or somewhere specific? Only the Bourne Supremacy's wikipedia article seemed to provide a link supplying some of this information. Any link with a map would be great in order to gauge the potential budget for such a trip.

Comment: try using www.imdb.com. Scroll down to filming locations and, if you're lucky, the list will be detailed. For The Bourne Supremacy, it has 33, some very specific, some more general http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0372183/locations?ref_=tt_dt_dt

Comment: @Dorothy Thanks, that is interesting, though perhaps a bit terse. For example it says Nerul when it would be nice to know that's referring to the Nerul bridge as in this site: http://www.sandspice.com/jason-bourne-footsteps/

Comment: +1 but are you asking for "how to find all of these locations?" (which might be a bit broad but nevermind) or "is there a resource that has all of these locations?"? Or put the other way round, what would your expected answer look like?

Comment: @mts I'd expect the answer to look a bit like Dorothy's comment. i.e. showing resources that let me figure out how to find these locations.

Comment: Are you asking as a potential *guide* or end-user in a self-guided experience?  When "The Da Vinci Code" was popular, there were lots of both types in Paris.  Also the British Recording Industry Trust has one http://britmovietours.com/bookings/london-film-locations-tour/  and I have a friend who guides one on "Sweeney Todd", knowing which side of the fence you're on can help.

Comment: @GayotFow Just an end user. I'd probably drag my son along and use him as the excuse I was there in the first place :)

Comment: @Berwyn given the industry, it may be the most readily available. Look in the forum; often afficionado add specifics. The film's location manager(s) might help, but that would require research. You could try through its guild locationmanagers.org via the member directory.

Comment: @Berwyn: Los Angeles has movie location bus tours, with a bonus of showing matching clips of the scenes.

Comment: Thanks @Dorothy but not looking for any sort of package or tour

Comment: Understood @Berwyn; it was just an add-on to show that there's certainly interest in this sort of tourism.

Comment: @Dorothy Oh right. Yes, I now see there certainly is

Answer (score 6):

@Dorothy gave a great link which I'd never noticed on imdb before. It appears that imdb users add locations that they recognise into imdb's database of filming locations, such as the one for the [Bourne Supremacy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0372183/locations). I thought I would take some of those locations and stick them into a google search to see if I could find other sites, e.g. [this search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22bourne%22%20%22nerul%22%20%22goa%22%20%22westin%22%20%22tempelhof%22).

The first link returned is to [movie-locations.com](http://www.movie-locations.com/movies/b/bourne_sup_1.html) which appears to contain quite a comprehensive list of locations and photos on this particular movie.

The second link is from [foursquare](https://foursquare.com/filmsq/list/the-bourne-supremacy-2004) and contains a map as well as user supplied descriptions of locations.

There are other links which might also be useful, but when adding in "nerul bridge" which wasn't mentioned in imdb, they disappeared.

Searching for a more recent movie such as [Terminator Genisys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_Genisys) wasn't as successful, but I'm not sure if that's due to the sites being out of date or the movie being too recent. movie-locations links to a [book on Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Worldwide-Guide-Movie-Locations-Updated/dp/1840239921) about the subject of this and names this phenomenon as movie tourism.

> Following the success of the original edition, this comprehensive,
>   international handbook to movie tourism has now been expanded and
>   completely updated, with over 70 new entries on films

However, the book is from 2006.

A whole [genre of tourism](https://www.virgin.com/travel/how-does-movie-tourism-change-a-citys-environment) that I didn't know [existed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop-culture_tourism).